# need to toggle table row that is being added dynamically with ajax

Tags: jquery, html

Each time I click the link, it adds a table row after the current row it is at, on success

```
$("#row"+id+"").after("<tr class='more-info' id='open"+id+"'><td colspan='13' class='mbg'>"+ html +"</td></tr>");
```

Each time I click the link, it adds another row, with the same exact info. What I want it to do when I click it a second time is to hide the row.

I thought appending .slideToggle() (below) would work, but it does not.

```
$("#row"+id+"").after("<tr class='more-info' id='open"+id+"'><td colspan='13' class='mbg'>"+ html +"</td></tr>").slideToggle();
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining won't do anything since you are not selecting the created element.  What you can do is select the next `tr` element and hide.  I'm guessing you probably don't want to create another row either.

```
.click(function(){
    if ($("#row" + id ).next('#open'+id).length > 0) {   // <-- check if there is a next row
        $("#row" + id ).next('#open'+id).slideToggle(); // <-- if there is just toggle next row
    } else {
        $("#row" + id + "").after("<tr class='more-info' id='open" + id + "'><td colspan='13' class='mbg'>testing</td></tr>");
        // else add new row
    }
});
```

EDIT:

1. ID's as numbers are not valid HTML.
2. ID's have to be unique

I modified my code above to check for next id with open also and it works fine in this fiddle.  I didn't change any of your html code but I would recommend fixing your ID's.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Zpej/

Comment: that didn't work. You are correct about not wanting to show more than one row of each.

Comment: @Brad  can you post some html markup?  also check your console if there are any errors

Comment: Thanks, that improved. I changed the id's to data-student="43", and retrieve the id var id = $(this.data('student'); I noticed the clicks don't do anything until after I clicked the link twice on each link. Something with the initial length for #row?

Comment: First click will only add the new row.  Second click should start the first slidetoggle

Comment: My mistake, I had a display:none; in the css for .more-info, that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of how you might make an object "slideToggle"-able on click:

```
$("#idToHide").click(function(){
   $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

Explanation:  First you need to attach a click handler.  You can do this jQuery's click function.  The click handler has access to the element that was clicked with `this`.  To hide the element, just select it with jQuery -- `$(this)` -- then `slideToggle()` it.

example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtPR8/)